# Merging two databases into one postgresql instance - Error user does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, pg-dump, pg-restore

PostgreSQL 10.7 question.
I have three PGSERVERs: LIVE1, LIVE2, and TRAIN

The LIVE1 and LIVE2 contain databases for my production data. The TRAIN area is for training and testing and contains a copy of LIVE1 and LIVE2 databases. We transfer them from each LIVE area into TRAIN using pg_dump followed by pg_restore. All of this is done as the postgres user.

Commands:

```
{set PG variables to LIVE1}
pg_dump -Fc ${PGDATABASE} > ${LIVE1DB}.dmp
{set PG variables to LIVE2}
pg_dump -Fc ${PGDATABASE} > ${LIVE2DB}.dmp
{set PG variables to TRAIN}
pg_restore -j 4 -d ${LIVE1DB} ${LIVE1DB}.dmp
pg_restore -j 4 -d ${LIVE2DB} ${LIVE2DB}.dmp
```

This is the first time that we are trying essentially a merge of two PGSERVERs into a third PGSERVER. Previously, we had a LIVE1 and LIVE2, and we would copy each one into TRAIN1 and TRAIN2 respectively. This change was to see if we could reduce overhead by reducing the quantity of PGSERVERs running on our systems.

I've noticed that for some reason when I perform the pg_restore, I am getting error messages about  "Role xxxx does not exist". This despite the fact that EVERY user that was in LIVE1 and LIVE2 (using \du) was already added to the TRAIN area.

Example:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 1485733; 0 0 ACL TABLE aitbpa_tbl postgres
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  role "bill" does not exist
    Command was: GRANT SELECT ON TABLE public.aitbpa_tbl TO svcl01;
```

What has me confused is that it complains that the one user does not exist, but then reports that the failing command was for a different user.

The two PGDATABASEs from LIVE1 and LIVE2 are restored just fine into the TRAIN PGSERVER area. We just have to go back and assign any missing GRANTs as necessary. But I'm curious if anyone else has ever encountered this issue. Is the only way to prevent this error from appearing is to use --no-acl and then add the desired grants later?

Thanks

Steve N.

--UPDATE--

Here is the pg_dumpall section for the users from LIVE1. (The md5 passwords were changed to xxx)

```
--
-- Roles
--

CREATE ROLE allan;
ALTER ROLE allan WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'md5xxx';
CREATE ROLE bill;
ALTER ROLE bill WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'md5xxx';
CREATE ROLE carol;
ALTER ROLE carolWITH NOSUPERUSER NOINHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB NOLOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'md5xxx';
CREATE ROLE jeff;
ALTER ROLE jeff WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'md5xxx';
CREATE ROLE kim;
ALTER ROLE kim WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB NOLOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'md5xxx';
CREATE ROLE postgres;
ALTER ROLE postgres WITH SUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEROLE CREATEDB LOGIN REPLICATION BYPASSRLS;
CREATE ROLE svcl01;
ALTER ROLE svcl01 WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'md5xxx';
CREATE ROLE tony;
ALTER ROLE tony WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'md5xxx';
```

This is the pg_dumpall for TRAIN area. It contains a few extra users that exist in the LIVE2 environment.

```
--
-- Roles
--

CREATE ROLE allan;
ALTER ROLE allan WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS;
CREATE ROLE bill;
ALTER ROLE bill WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'md5xxx';
CREATE ROLE carol;
ALTER ROLE carol WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'md5xxx';
CREATE ROLE jeff;
ALTER ROLE jeff WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'md5xxx';
CREATE ROLE kim;
ALTER ROLE kim WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'md5xxx';
CREATE ROLE michelle;
ALTER ROLE michelle WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS;
CREATE ROLE postgres;
ALTER ROLE postgres WITH SUPERUSER INHERIT CREATEROLE CREATEDB LOGIN REPLICATION BYPASSRLS;
CREATE ROLE svcl01;
ALTER ROLE svcl01 WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'md5xxx';
CREATE ROLE svcl02;
ALTER ROLE svcl02 WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS PASSWORD 'md5xxx';
CREATE ROLE tony;
ALTER ROLE tony WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN NOREPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS;
```

The error was produced from the pg_restore that was done for LIVE1. But as you can see the user "bill" exists in both.

The only thing I was suspecting was that if we restored LIVE2, perhaps it eliminates the roles that do NOT exist in that PGSERVER. Because bill exists in LIVE1 and TRAIN, but not in LIVE2. But then I would have expected michelle and svcl02 to have been lost in TRAIN after restoring LIVE1 because they only exist in LIVE2.

Comment: Obviously "bill" was not added to TRAIN. Have you run `pg_dumpall -g` on the LIVE* databases to get the roles? Also check whether "svc101" has `INHERIT`(it is the default) set and whether it has a relationship to "bill". Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: Roles are global to the cluster, once they are added they stay until explicitly dropped. A restore to one database will not drop the roles in another database. As to your issue, did you restore the `pg_dumpall -g -f dumpall_globals.sql` file to the TRAIN cluster before doing the `pg_restore`(s)? This would require something like `psql -d postgres -U postgres -d <train_port_no> -f dumpall_globals.sql` as it is a plain text file.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think I finally have an explanation to the issue I reported. The operator who was handling the pg_restore neglected to mention that AFTER they restored the backup and received the errors about the "`role does not exist`", they went ahead and actually created the missing role.

This explains things for me because it also tells me why the GRANTS did not exist when I was investigating. They ran the `CREATE USER`, but did not also go and issue the GRANT commands afterwards. I am told I would have seen the user created in my log if it was logging DDL statements, which it was not.

As Adrian pointed out, roles are global to the cluster (PGSERVER level), but the GRANTS are at PGDATABASE level. So I was having a hard time figuring why one would affect the other. This was just the first time our team had set up a situation where databases from two clusters get transferred into one cluster.

As usual, we should look at the simplest answer before considering it might be something else. Thanks for viewing it and maybe it will help others.